# Podio web hooks not working

Tags: podio

I created a web hook for item update in podio for calling a dream factory service.In that service I added verification code for podio webhook and got verified from the podio.The service I written is for uploading some files to dropbox and if it is invoked, the files will be uploaded to dropbox.But when the item is updated in podio,it doesn't call the webhook.How can I check whether the webhook is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create new webhook and used some service like https://requestbin.com to debug and verify that is all work well.

Comment: link is dead. Also fix it in the documentation

Comment: updated link, also this question is not about documentation